# Comando de saída ou passar a saída em php

Tags: javascript

Olá.

Quero retornar a mensagem de sucesso caso seja inserido um nome no array. E quero exibir os nomes nesse array.

Não quero usar alert(). O document.write não funciona bem em funções, principalmente com eventos ou funções temporizadoras. Já fiz testes com temporizadoras e eventos, mas aparecem outras coisas na tela e não o que eu quero. Já com alert() funciona. Existe outro comando de saída?

Ou talvez, eu possa usar o php para exibir a mensagem de sucesso e os nomes do array. Como passo do javascript para php?

Seguem duas funções javascript para tal.

```
<script>
    j = 0;
    i = 0;

    nomes = new Array();

    function inserirNome() {
        nome = prompt("informe o nome");

        nomes[i] = nome;

        alert("Nome inserido");
        i++;
    }

    function verNomes() {

        while (j < i) {
            alert(nomes[j]);

            j++
        }

        if (i == 0) {
            alert("Não tem nome inserido");
        }

    }
</script>

<a onclick="inserirNome()"> Inserir um nome</a>

<a onclick="verNomes()"> Ver os nomes inseridos</a>
```

Comment: Aqui está a funcionar normalmente com o `getElementById`, inclusive o `document.write`.

Answer (score 0):

Experimenta isto, é também uma boa forma de imprimir retornos no corpo do documento.

```js
var nomes = [];
var div = document.getElementById('mensagem');

function inserirNome() {
  var nome = prompt('Insira o nome');
  if (nome) {
    if (nomes.push(nome)) {
      div.innerHTML = ('inserido: ' + nome);
    }
  }
}

function verNomes() {
  var nick = '',
    x = 0;
  nomes.forEach(function(nome) {
    nick += 'Nome' + x + ':' + nome + "<br/>";
    x++;
  });
  if (nick == '') {
    div.innerHTML = 'Nenhum nome encontrado';
    return;
  }
  div.innerHTML = nick;
}
```

```html
<div id="mensagem"></div>
<a href="#" onclick="inserirNome()"> Inserir um nome</a>
<a href="#" onclick="verNomes()"> Ver os nomes inseridos</a>
```

Comment: Não funcionou para listar os nomes.

Comment: Havia um erro ao fechar a tag `div`, reeditei código, experimenta agora.

Comment: Solução interessante Edilson +1... @AndréNascimento, clique acima, em "Executar trecho de código" pra ver funcionando no snippet...